# Rabl How to render heterogeneous content with partials/extends

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

I have this rabl view that will display either a user or a place, depending of the output of my controller. I tried many things to make it work but I cannot seem to find the right syntax.

Here is my current rabl template (*main.rabl*) that's returning

*undefined method `key?' for JSON::Ext::Generator::State:0xcac9520*

```
object false

if @user
  child @user do
    extends 'user'
  end
end

if @place
  child @place do
    extends 'place'
  end
end
```

And here is the user template (*user.rabl*):

```
object @user => :user
attributes :id, :email, :firstname, :lastname
```

The extends works pretty well for collections, but it cannot seem to work for this case.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: use something like this ""collection :@posts => :articles"" as i got it from [documentation](https://github.com/ccocchi/rabl-rails)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work...Besides I just have one item to render

Comment: The solution I got was with a custom node https://github.com/nesquena/rabl#custom-nodes